# How stable is the Ubuntu One nightly build ppa?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one, ppa

I am using ubuntu 10.04 so it is an older version of ubuntu one and had no control panel. I noticed there is a lucid version in the nightly build ppa and was wondering how stable it is

Answer (score 2):

The nightly PPA is an automatic build with no testing - at best packages either compile or dont compile on a daily basis.  I would stay clear of this PPA.

My suggestion therefore would have been to install either `ubuntuone-control-panel` or `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` - the latter package gives you a GTK type interface for Ubuntu-One.

However these packages are only available for Maverick and Natty.  They have not been backported to Lucid.  There is one potential PPA available with these packages backported.  However, as the author himself says - use with care.  **Therefore - take the authors advice and backup first using a good backup tool such as Clonezilla**

### To Install on Lucid

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kalon33/experimental-stuff
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppa:kalon33/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

**NOW VERY IMPORTANT**

Open your software sources and untick both the Kalon33 experimental PPA and Kalon33 PPA.  The reason is that you probably will not want any of the authors extensive builds for Lucid.

Finish off running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### Running UbuntuOne

The package will install Ubuntu-One under the Settings menu.